# How to integrate Angular 4 with an existing Spring Boot jsp based web app?

Tags: angular, jsp, spring-boot

I have an existing Spring Boot production web app, utilizing jsp and javascript.  I would like to replace existing pages (one or 2 at a time), with Angular **as time permits**.  I am new to Angular, and all the doc/posts that I've encountered seem that Angular is an all or nothing scenario.  For starters, how would I go about replacing a page in the app which can be found at this address /cust/AccountSampleQuery?active=y ?  The user is authenticated at this point, and has selected this address from a menu.

Comment: angular won't run as a jsp inside your project. angular will be alone, and doing some request to your java web app. so you need to build a rest api first)

Comment: Yes, I understand that Angular is client side, and I will need a REST api.  I am struggling with when the user clicks the menu option to the /cust/AccountSampleQuery, that angular "intercepts" the request, and displays the initial page, user enters data on the page, clicks submit, and angular submits the REST request, and the processes the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is kind of easy to integrate with Spring RESTful api if you're writing it fresh, but its not impossible to integrate in your case. Angula work on the same principal as AJAX but more OOP look to it like Java.

You will need to replace your existing JSP approach with rest API approach, where you have rest controllers to handle incoming web requests (JSON for post and query params and path variables) and response back with `HttpStatus` codes and JSON objects.

The authentication has to be replaced with something like JWT or any kind of token based authentication. As Angular is hard to run session based and more like token based. So every request must accompany a token if it is going to a secure part of the API.

The if you wish to package the Angular app along side Spring API (`.jar` or `.war` file), you're going to need `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` to configure static content paths. Here's an example static content path:

```html
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("**/assets/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/assets");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/index.html");
    }
}
```

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'customer', component: CustomerComponent},
  {path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true})
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

Comment: Do I have to use the angular index.html, or can I use something more meaningful , like customer.html?  Also I have an admin side of the app where I'd like to use admin.html, instead of index.html.

Comment: In Angular is a component based system; That means there are no pages. You have single page `index.html` and all other HTML files are loaded on to it depending on router navigation. Everything is managed by  `RouterModule` so your ULR can be something like `http://localhost/admin` or `http://localhost/customer `. Router will manage this. I'll add sample Router. It is possible to change the `index.html` to something but I dont believe there's a point to it as will mainly used to load the `<app-root></app-root>` and `<base href="/">`

Comment: {useHash: true} saved my night. I had a problem launching my app with a JSP which is something like /jsp/myapp/index.jsp.
Without this option, I can't launch my app with a pre-defined route, something like /jsp/myapp/event/123 because it didn't know to load index.jsp. With the hash option, it could understand /jsp/myapp/#/event/123. I knew this in AngularJS but didn't know how to turn it on in Angular 5. Thanks!